# Syntax error when installing the spkg package of wxPython on Sage

Tags: python, wxpython, sage

When I want to install the package wxPython-2.8.7.1.spkg from [here](http://www.sagemath.org/packages/experimental/)

in the terminal of Sage it gives me a syntax error. What i write in Sage terminal and the result are as follow:

```
sage: sage -i wxPython-2.8.7.1.spkg
------------------------------------------------------------
   File "<ipython console>", line 1
     sage -i wxPython-RealNumber('2.8').gen(7).1.spkg
                    ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

I also use the direct address of the package but the result was the same:

```
 sage: sage -i http://www.sagemath.org/packages/experimental/wxPython-2.8.7.1.s>
------------------------------------------------------------
   File "<ipython console>", line 1
     sage -i http://www.sagemath.org/packages/experimental/wxPython-RealNumber('2.8').gen(7).1.spkg
                ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

I also downloaded the package and used the local address but the result was the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to do this from the command line before *starting* Sage.  Otherwise you can use

```
sage: install_package("wxPython")
```

which is currently downloading for me... and then failed:

```
checking for GTK+ - version >= 2.0.0... no
*** Could not run GTK+ test program, checking why...
*** The test program failed to compile or link. See the file config.log for the
*** exact error that occured. This usually means GTK+ is incorrectly installed.
configure: error:
The development files for GTK+ were not found. For GTK+ 2, please
ensure that pkg-config is in the path and that gtk+-2.0.pc is
installed. For GTK+ 1.2 please check that gtk-config is in the path,
and that the version is 1.2.3 or above. Also check that the
libraries returned by 'pkg-config gtk+-2.0 --libs' or 'gtk-config
--libs' are in the LD_LIBRARY_PATH or equivalent.
Error configure wx widgets.

real    0m13.972s
user    0m2.791s
sys 0m5.232s
************************************************************************
Error installing package wxPython-2.8.7.1
************************************************************************
```

Along those lines, here is what it says at [the list of experimental spkgs](http://sagemath.org/packages/experimental/), of which this is one:

> These are EXPERIMENTAL! They probably won't work at all for you! Use at your own risk! Many of these have *never* been successfully built on any platform!

So buyer beware!

Comment: Though in this case it does give you some ideas for how you might fix it.  "Optional" spkgs should install fine on all supported platforms.